# How to call a class in the App_Code folder from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a class in ASP.NET C# which is located in the App_Code folder. Now I want to call this class from my code behind from one of my .aspx pages. How can I do this?

Any help will be appreciate it.

Comment: There's no extra step needed, it should work.

Comment: It doesn't, how can I call this class? can you give me an example?? I'll appreciate it.

Comment: what is the problem exactly, do you get a build error?

Comment: Nothing, I'm trying to figure out how to call it? Basically the code to do so

Comment: `var a = new MyClass(); a.DoSomething();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After building the project to enable Intellisense, type the Namespace of the class first, or add a using statement with the Namespace.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example of the code to do this?? I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that you can't see the App_Code class from your code-behind, right? Go to the solution explorer and in the properties of the class, change the Build Action to `Compile`. After making this change, you should be able to access the class in your code-behind.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, will this be in the same spot?

Comment: I would imagine so. In the right pane, where your project files are listed, right-click on the class under App_Code and select properties. Should be a property called "Build Action"

Comment: Weird, is only showing a Title of "Misc" the Custom Tool, File Name and Full Path properties.

Answer (score 2):

in file of class in App_Code folder just change attribute "Build Action" to Compile

Answer (score 0):

You can access your code if you've put it in the App_Code folder. Code in there is compiled dynamically at run time, and is available for you to use anywhere, so long as your classes are public. You want to make sure you get the namespace correct. Suggest something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace.App_Code {
    public class MyClass {
```

Then, in your code reference this using:

```
MyNamespace.App_Code.MyClass x = new MyNamespace.App_Code.MyClass();
```