# Mixing C# and VB.Net in ASP.Net App_Code folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have successfully access a class from VB to C# when I put the VB files to a folder and write this line of codes to web.config

```html
<compilation>
  <codeSubDirectories>
     <add directoryName="VB" />
     <add directoryName="CSharp" />
  </codeSubDirectories>
</compilation>
```

Now for some reason, I don't want to put the VB files to a sub directory and just put it to App_Code, like this.

[image]

However, I'm having an error when I'm trying to access the class from VB to C#. Here.

[image]

My question is, is it possible to access the class from VB to C# without putting the VB files to a sub directory? What should I add to web.config to make them connected? Thank you.

Comment: Try using reference to `App_Code` namespace, e.g. `using Website.App_Code`, then you can use `App` class. If it still doesn't work, set build action for VB files inside `App_Code` directory to `Compile`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Actually I already tried that too and still can't. Just giving an error _namespace could not be found_ . By setting a build action do you mean by this? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498245/how-to-set-build-action-on-a-file-advanced-properties-not-displayed-in-propert]

Comment: You're right, that's where the "Compile" option you should set to all VB code files inside App_Code directory **first** before trying to reference App class using its namespace (`using Website.App_Code`). Give a shot & see if it works properly.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Can't find the Build Action

Comment: Right-click your VB code file, then choose Properties. There is an option called `Build Action` in Properties window and ensure it already set to "Compile". Also check if VB namespaces are arranged properly (set them to `Website.App_Code` if isn't).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, right-click every VB code file and navigate to "Properties" window to see properties of each file, then ensure all of them already have `Build Action` set to `Compile` mode such like this:

[image: Build Action Compile]

If you're copied VB.NET code files from other location to `App_Code` directory or found using any different namespace(s), don't forget to set their current namespace properly:

```vb
Namespace Website.App_Code
    Module App
       ...
       ' App class contents here

       ...
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Then, you can use `Website.App_Code.App` class by referencing its namespace:

```
using Website.App_Code; 

public class Practice
{
    public static string AttachmentDirectory => App.Attachment;
}
```

Note that `App` class needs to be set as `public` scope so that it can be accessed by all instances across your project.

**NB:** The `AttachmentDirectory` property seems assigned with [expression-bodied member syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) which applicable to version 6.0 or above. *Check for currently used compiler version* to use that kind of syntax.

Similar issues:

[Classes residing in App_Code is not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222281/classes-residing-in-app-code-is-not-accessible)

[How to call a class in the App_Code folder from code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855948/how-to-call-a-class-in-the-app-code-folder-from-code-behind)

Comment: I don't know the problem, but there's no "Properties" item in the menu when I right click a VB file.

Comment: By the way I'm using ASP.net web forms, not ASP.net MVC. May I know the version of your VS?

Comment: Currently I've using VS 2013 & 2015, and Properties context menu still exist for both editions. If you can't use properties from context menu, use View => Properties Window to display the window and just click VB file you want to see its properties.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that either. But still there's no build action drop down.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<compilation>
  <codeSubDirectories>
     <add directoryName="VB" />
     <add directoryName="CSharp" />
  </codeSubDirectories>
</compilation>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).